# how to use a drop down to select an element and scroll down to that element's detail in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, scroll, ngfor

My data look like this :

```
groups: [
{
 collections:[]
},
{
 collections:[]
}]
```

I am using nested *ngFor to display all groups and collections at the same page, the list becomes long when there are many groups and collection.In the header, I have dropdowns, one for each group

[image]

from there a user can select any one collection, now I want to automatically scroll down to that collection on the page when a collection is selected.

note that each collection can have the different height in DOM depending upon the details inside that collection.

Comment: I'd use local anchor tags with hashes: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know the name for each dropdown element, and have a block in your html that corresponds, you can do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="unique_id_to_use"></div>
</div>
```

Then you can use the select event handler:

```
(select)="onSelect($event)"
```

In your class (I'm going from memory here, the syntax might not be correct):

```
onSelect(event) {
  // Use querySelector with a name that corresponds to the named div
  // passed in from (for example) the value of your dropdown i.e.
  // the aforementioned unique_id_to_use
  let el = document.querySelector(event.target.value);
  if (el) {
    el.scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

There are various options to use with scrollIntoView(), smooth scrolling, etc., which you can view on the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

Comment: Thanks, scrollIntoView() saved the day!